# Elasticsearch query: Multiply final score using nested object and function score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with some data and a specific **omit** list in it (see [mapping](https://gist.github.com/baloghz/303c8eeaa29b9d3f99e2/bcc67a338bf08daeca972cc724e5df8afbaf5d50#file-omit_list-sh-L8-L38) and [example data](https://gist.github.com/baloghz/303c8eeaa29b9d3f99e2/bcc67a338bf08daeca972cc724e5df8afbaf5d50#file-omit_list-sh-L40-L97)):

I would like to write an ES query which does the following:

1. Calculate some "basic" score for the documents (Query 1):

   ```
   {
     "explain": true,
     "query": {
       "bool": {
         "should": [
           {
             "constant_score": {
               "filter": {
                 "term": {
                   "type": "TYPE1"
                 }
               }
             }
           },
           {
             "function_score": {
               "linear": {
                 "number": {
                   "origin": 30,
                   "scale": 20
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. At the end multiply the score according to the omit percent of a specific id (In the example I used omit valut for **A**`"omit.id": "A"`). As a demonstration in Query 2 I calculated this multiplier.

   ```
   {
     "query": {
       "nested": {
         "path": "omit",
         "query": {
           "function_score": {
             "query": {
               "filtered": {
                 "query": {
                   "match_all": {}
                 },
                 "filter": {
                   "term": {
                     "omit.id": "A"
                   }
                 }
               }
             },
             "functions": [
               {
                 "linear": {
                   "omit.percent": {
                     "origin": 0,
                     "scale": 50,
                     "offset": 0,
                     "decay": 0.5
                   }
                 }
               }
             ],
             "score_mode": "multiply"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

To achieve this final multiplication I faced with the following problems:

- If I calculate linear function score inside of a nested query, (according to my interpretation) I cannot use any other field in `function_score` query.
- I cannot multiply the calculated score with any other `function_score` which is encapsulated into a nested query.

I would like to ask for any advice to resolve this issue.

Note that maybe I should get rid of this nested type and use key-value pairs instead. For example:

```
{
  "omit": {
    "A": {
      "percent": 10
    },
    "B": {
      "percent": 100
    }
  }
}
```

but unfortunately there will be a lot of keys, which would result a huge (continuously growing) mapping, so I not prefer this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least I figured out a possible solution based on a "non-nested way". The complete script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/baloghz/df220072123396f6a7a6/fead7e7be5c4e79e0b1ed0ac91bd357c5d72f569).

I modified the omit list as described in the question:

```
"omit": {
  "A": {
    "percent": 10
  },
  "B": {
    "percent": 100
  }
}
```

In addition I set the `enabled` flag to `false` to not have these elements in the mapping:

```
"omit": {
  "type" : "object",
  "enabled" : false
}
```

The last trick was to use `script_score` as a `function_score`'s function, because only there I could use the value of `percent` by `_source.omit.A.percent` script:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        ...
      },
      "script_score": {
        "lang": "groovy",
        "script": "if (_source.omit.A){(100-_source.omit.A.percent)/100} else {1}"
      },
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```